# Scan a google document line by line

Tags: node.js, google-docs, google-docs-api, discord.js, roblox

so basically, I'm trying to use node.js to scan a google document, then if a ROBLOX id is on there it tracks it. When it tracks it, if it joins one of the groups in the id list, it auto-exiles it.

Any help?

I'm a little stuck on the scanning a google document line by line.

Comment: Can you use a text file? If so I can probably help you out here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about how to do it from a google doc, but if you are willing to move to using text files(`.txt`) I think I could be of assistance.

Using Nodes FS we can read lines using a [Line reader](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_readstream)

```
import * as fs from 'fs'
import { createReadStream } from 'fs'
import { createInterface } from 'readline'

const lineReader = createInterface({
  input: createReadStream('data/input.txt')
})

const output: string[] = []

lineReader.on('line', (item: string) => {
  output.push(If you wanna output something to an output file put it here)
})

// Down here is the output of what you put in the output.push

lineReader.on('close', () => {
  fs.writeFile('data/output.txt', output.join('\n'), err => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('The file has been saved!')
  })
})
```

So the above code is in typescript, but typescript can be compiled down into javascript. If this code doesn't work for you I at least hope it gave some knowledge that helped you find your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @ScratchCoder If it gave you your answer or lead to it remember to accept it :)

Comment: I'm still testing it so I'm not sure if it's right.

Comment: Yeah thats all good, I'm not sure how advanced you are but [this is a compiler for typescript to javascript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)